# Jquery hide list of divs and show in sections of 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have myself a html page like so

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I have already is in my document ready function I have this.

```
var sections = $(".content");
        for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i+=5) {
            sections.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll("<div class='section-of-content'></div>");
        }
```

This splits my divs up and wraps them in a new div with the class "section-of-content", now what I would like to do is simply show the first "section-of-content" and hide all the others, then I will have an anchor tag at the bottom which is next and previous which will show and hide the other "section-of-content".

I have tried this

```
var contentSections = $(".section-of-content");
        for(var i = 0; i < contentSections.length; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            { 
                contentSections [i].show();
            }
            else
            {
                contentSections [i].hide();
            }
        }
```

But it states that a function is undefined, it is referring to .show();
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You have spaces between "contentSections" and [i], there should be no spaces there. Also, put a debugger in an make sure the value of "i" is a number and not undefined.

Comment: Can you make a runnable example--either in a snippet or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap `projectSections[i]` in jquery selector because `projectSections[i]` gives you a javascript element and not a jquery object, so if you use it like:

```
var projectSections = $(".project-section");
for(var i = 0; i < projectSections.length; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
    { 
        $(projectSections[i]).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(projectSections[i]).hide();
    }
}
```

it would work no problem. but I suggest you use this instead:

```
$(".project-section").hide();
$(".project-section:first-child").show();
```

it's more practical.

Comment: Boom, can't believe I missed that. Perspective.